# Weird jumps in Android MotionEvent touch position

Tags: android, input, touch, touch-event, motionevent

I've implemented a simple scrollable gallery type view on Android using code similar to this:

```
private int mPos; // The current scroll position.
private int mLastMostionPos; // Previous touch position.

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    final int action = ev.getAction();

    Log.d(TAG, "Mouse mLastMotionPos: " + mLastMotionPos + " ev.getX(): " + ev.getX() + " mPos: " + mPos + " ev.getPointerId(0): " + ev.getPointerId(0)
            + " ev.getEventTime(): " + ev.getEventTime());

    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // Remember where the motion event started
        mLastMotionPos = (int)ev.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        final int pos = (int)ev.getX(activePointerIndex);
        // Scroll to follow the motion event
        int delta = mLastMotionPos - pos;
        mLastMotionPos = pos;

        mPos += delta;
        if (mPos < mMinPos)
            mPos = mMinPos;
        if (mPos > mMaxPos)
            mPos = mMaxPos;
        break;
```

And it works but I noticed that sometimes it will suddently "jump" a little. It's really only noticeable when you are scrolling to one end. If you are already scrolled all the way to the right, and you move your finger always to the right, *occasionally* the thing will jump left for one frame.

I added the logging line above and obtained this output (edited for readability):

```
50.913: Mouse mLastMotionPos: 304 ev.getX(): 379.0 mPos: 0 ev.getPointerId(0): 0 ev.getEventTime(): 111690077
50.928: Mouse mLastMotionPos: 379 ev.getX(): 369.0 mPos: 0 ev.getPointerId(0): 0 ev.getEventTime(): 111690093
50.943: Mouse mLastMotionPos: 369 ev.getX(): 384.0 mPos: 10 ev.getPointerId(0): 0 ev.getEventTime(): 111690109
50.958: Mouse mLastMotionPos: 384 ev.getX(): 391.0 mPos: 0 ev.getPointerId(0): 0 ev.getEventTime(): 111690125
50.983: Mouse mLastMotionPos: 391 ev.getX(): 399.0 mPos: 0 ev.getPointerId(0): 0 ev.getEventTime(): 111690141
51.023: Mouse mLastMotionPos: 399 ev.getX(): 399.0 mPos: 0 ev.getPointerId(0): 0 ev.getEventTime(): 111690186
```

Note that it jumps 10 pixels! I swear I was only dragging my finger to the right, and being quite deliberate about it. At first I thought Android might be delivering the events out-of-order or something, but the event times are monotonic.

Any idea why this is happening? I suppose it could be Samsung's fault (I have a Galaxy S2). It *does* have [a retarded driver-imposed touch threshold](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRXcBcpSD1w) so whoever wrote the input drivers clearly didn't know what they were doing. Still, 10 pixels seems like a big jump. And sometimes it is even bigger!

Answer (score 2):

A little bit later but maybe it's gonna be useful for somebody else, if you're interested only in the Delay and not in the actual MotionEvent position you can use the getRawX() and getRawY() methods. I was having the exact same issue and I change the way in which I was getting the coordinates and voila !!! It was working.

Comment: You can get the values of any pointer you want through getRawX(int) and getRawY(int) : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX(int)

Comment: getRawX() and getRawY() don't work for other pointer except single touch.

Comment: Well, maybe if you read the link I posted you'll notice that it works for several pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact logic behind this, but I was facing the same issue

The issue is **not "hardware" related**,as I had tested it on **3 different devices** (One sony and other two were of samsung), but it gave the same result everywhere.. 
It behaves the same even on emulator...

I was facing it in case of "vertical swipe".Although I was swiping a few pixels, It Was giving a huge difference of 150px(or greater than that).

I was almost fed up of this weired jump

But when I copied the same code in my "Demoapplication" so as to play with it,it worked like a charm there.

**Solution :-**

I just replaced `ScrollView` from my XML layout (which was my parent layout for swipe and may be the sole reason behind the issue too), and everything was sorted after that...

I hope `ScrollView` is the culprit in you case also.

BTW I am using this as [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8806468/1206052) to implement swipe in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting a similar issue. For me, it turned out I was saving away a MotionEvent from my event handler and reissuing it later. This is bad because MotionEvents are forced garbage collected. If you want to make a copy, you need to make a copy like this:

```
val copy = MotionEvent.obtain(event)
```

If you do make a copy like this, don't forget to recycle it yourself when you are done with it:

```
copy.recycle()
```

Answer (score -1):

Possibly hardware related?    Have you tried on a more powerful device?

Comment: Yes I speculated this in the question. See the last paragraph. I sadly don't have any other phones to try it on right now, but that seems like the best next step unless this is a known issue.

Comment: I've noticed 5-10 pixel jumps on my tablets (TAB2 7 inch and 10.1 inch) when drawing on screen which i accounted to hardware issues but I was never able to find the exact cause.